# Let $ϕ_X(t)$ be the characteristic function of $X$ with $|ϕ_X(t_0)| = 1$ for some $t_0 \neq 0$. Then $P(X \in b + \frac{2π}{t_0} \mathbb{N}) = 1$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $ϕ_X(t)$ be the characteristic function of an r.v $X$ with $|ϕ_X(t_0)| = 1$ for some $t_0 \neq 0$. Prove that
$$P(X \in b + \frac{2π}{t_0} \mathbb{N}) = 1$$
for some $b ∈ \mathbb{R}$.
Hint: Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to show that variance of $\sin(t_0X)$, $\cos(t_0X)$ is zero.
I'm actually very stuck, don't know where to start, also I think I proved $Var(\sin t_0X)=0$ (without using C-S, don't know how right I am), but I'm stuck for $Var(\cos t_0X)=0$. Also I understand how this would imply that $X \in b + \frac{2π}{t_0} \mathbb{N}$ a.s.
So any hits are appreciated.

Comment: Bad hint. This standard result (found in many books) has a simlper proof.